# Shared cache between different servers

Tags: caching, microservices, hazelcast

Am trying to implement a shared cache application, I have 4 different servers which should use that cache, am also concerned with the response time, the response need to be as fast as possible, so my question is, which method should I go with ?

1 - something like Hazelcast or 
2 - implement it as a single application and expose/access it through webservice, something like a microservice application ...

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: Do you know the likely breakdown of reads compared to writes ? What's the tolerance for staleness -- must the cache contents be 100% accurate or can you accept fractionally old cached results (note: fractionally!). You can improve performance in the latter case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hazelcast allows concurrency across JVMs / applications. A hazelcast data structure and its contents are available across Client application or Nodes within the cluster. Hazelcast manages the consistency. The helps to share cache/data across applications. You can also control data partitioning or affinity leading to fewer networks hops during fetching data, query or executing tasks on the cache server.

Kindly refer to documentation in hazelcast website and guide as below.
Mastering Hazelcast : https://hazelcast.com/resources/mastering-hazelcast/
Code Samples : https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples

Hope this helps